# How can I save acrobat reader digital signature validation result?

Tags: validation, digital-signature, acrobat

I have just received request from end user that there is a need to save the verification result of digital signature in PDF file. I have searched in internet but no good news for it can be found.

So, is there anyone having any clue on how to do so i.e. after opening digitally signed PDF using Acrobat Reader DC, I can save the verification result (especially the validation time) to another file?

Thanks!
Michael

Comment: Have you tried command-line tools that support PDF signature verification?

Comment: If you are a programmer, or have access to one, you could using a library that supports the PDF structure. For example, the [LEADTOOLS PDF Toolkit](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/pdf) can [extract and parse](https://www.leadtools.com/blog/document-imaging/pdf/retrieve-digital-signature-information-pdfs-leadtools) the validation status and dates of digital signatures in a PDF. (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor). If you want to try it for yourself, there is a [free evaluation](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads) available for this SDK.

Comment: Refer to https://help.signer.digital/pdf_signature_verification_api.htm for API available in commercial product.

Answer (score 0):

Just print and select the printer to be the one that saves the content as PDF (Microsoft Printer to PDF in case of Windows).